# Keyboard Extension can no longer submit to iTunes after adding groups

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm creating my second keyboard extension app. I've been submitting through iTunes TestFlight for testing for a couple months with no problems. But after making two changes, it no longer submits. I get the error "Failed to locate or generate matching signed assets and ailed to do so because of the following issues.

"not matching provisioning profiles found for "Applications/spkapp.app/Plugins/spk.appex"

None of the valid provision profiles allowed the specified entitlements: beta-reports-active, com.apple.security.application-groups"

The two changes I've made were to the Bundle Display Name and adding the Groups entitlement. My app ids for the extension and app both have Groups activated and set to the same group.

I've tried

1) Restoring Bundle Display Name to previous name.

2) Rebuilding all profiles several dozen times

3) Creating new profiles from scratch.

4) Refreshing profiles in Xcode, even downloading them and installing new ones and deleting the old manually.

5) Cleaning/deleting derived data/restarting Xcode/rebooting OSX

6) Comparing it to my shipping keyboard that uses the Groups entitlement. Everything matches from the entitlement files to the project settings to the provisioning profiles to the App IDs settings.

I think the problem is something to do with the Groups obviously, since it's the new addition. But I did look at Technical Q&A QA1830, but it doesn't seem helpful because I have a Store provisioning profile and it was working, so the beta-reports-active flag seems like a spurious error.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was caused by adding the Groups entitlement. Xcode creates a custom app ID for your keyboard extension, with a name starting with "Xcode iOS App ID" followed by your bundle IDs. The App ID itself will be the combined bundle ids of your app/extension as the App ID such as com.companyname.appBundleID.extensionBundleID. It's settings will match your other AppIDs, including the App Group settings.

It will also create a distribution profile for this App ID, and you need this distribution profile in order to submit to the store with groups enabled. The distribution profile will be named something like "XC: com.companyname:appBundleID.extensionBundleID".  If this isn't installed when you submit to the store, you will get the error that your plugin does not have a correct profile with the groups entitlement as described above.

Note: I could submit to the story with the group entitlements disabled, so it seems this profile is only needed when you have specific entitlements enabled.

In my case, i don't know if Xcode neglected to create the distribution profile, or I deleted it when trying to clean up. To fix it I just created my own distribution profile for the Xcode App ID and named it in the same way, and ensured it was installed in Xcode 6.1 ( preferences: Apple ID view details: refresh button).  And now my keyboard submits properly, with group entitlements active.